# javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:82) Null pointer exception

Tags: java, wso2, jax-ws, java-11

When constructor of Service class called i am getting below exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:82)
```

I am facing this issue after Java 11 Update . 
The Service class used from `org.wso2.orbit.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-ri_2.3.2.wso2v1.jar`
The arguments for constructor are not null.

Comment: could you share the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Also could you be more informative about the way you are creating the instance of service?